# How to get a single object by LINQ? ERROR: The result of a query cannot be enumerated more than once

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

My code like this:

```
    private void BindGvUsersInRole ()
    {
        var aRole =
            (from aspnet_Roles rol
                 in _allRoles
            where rol.RoleId.ToString() == ddlRoles.SelectedValue
            select rol).SingleOrDefault();

        this.gvUsersInRole.DataSource = aRole.aspnet_Users;
        this.gvUsersInRole.DataBind();
    }
```

I got an error on the last line:

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The result of a query cannot be enumerated more than once.

then I amend the function like this(thanks @VitaliyKalinin):

```
private void BindGvUsersInRole ()
{
    Guid  roleID=new Guid(ddlRoles.SelectedValue);

    var users =
    (
        from aspnet_Roles rol in _allRoles
        from u in rol.aspnet_Users
        where rol.RoleId == roleID
        select u
    ).ToList();

    this.gvUsersInRole.DataSource = users;
    this.gvUsersInRole.DataBind();
}
```

STILL SAME ERROR!!!!

what happens!?!?

the "aspnet_Users" property :

```
    /// <summary>
    /// 没有元数据文档可用。
    /// </summary>
    [XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    [SoapIgnoreAttribute()]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    [EdmRelationshipNavigationPropertyAttribute("realtydbModel", "aspnet_UsersInRoles", "aspnet_Users")]
    public EntityCollection<aspnet_Users> aspnet_Users
    {
        get
        {
            return ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedCollection<aspnet_Users>("realtydbModel.aspnet_UsersInRoles", "aspnet_Users");
        }
        set
        {
            if ((value != null))
            {
                ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.InitializeRelatedCollection<aspnet_Users>("realtydbModel.aspnet_UsersInRoles", "aspnet_Users", value);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: aRole.DefaultIfEmpty(). It will return null or first element

Comment: ON which line you got this exception? Also what is `_allRoles` and how it populated?

Comment: @sll the last line;;;; Guid  roleID=new Guid(ddlRoles.SelectedValue);

            var users =
            (
                from aspnet_Roles rol in _allRoles
                from u in rol.aspnet_Users
                where rol.RoleId == roleID
                select u
            );
            
            this.gvUsersInRole.DataSource = users;
            this.gvUsersInRole.DataBind();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Single` or `SingleOrDefault()` todo this:

```
// parse the string `ddlRoles.SelectedValue` into the appropriate type as `roleID`
var roleID = ParseRoleID(ddlRoles.SelectedValue);
var aRole = (from rol in aspnet_Roles.Include("aspnet_Users")
            where rol.RoleId == roleID 
            select rol).Single();
```

However this will throw an exception if there is more than one entity returned. If you just want the first entity that matches the case you can use `First()`or `FirstOrDefault()`:

```
var roleID = ParseRoleID(ddlRoles.SelectedValue);
var aRole = (from rol in aspnet_Roles.Include("aspnet_Users")
            where rol.RoleId == roleID 
            select rol).First();
```

The `OrDefault`versions of these methods make sure you don't get an exception if there is no match. It will return null instead.

Also:
Rather than using `ToString()` on the `RoleId` parse the `ddlRoles.SelectedValue` into the appropriate type before you use it in the LINQ query since some methods (`ToString()` is one of them) are not supported within a LINQ query that executes against a DB.

Comment: Worth pointing out that `Single()` and `First()` will both throw exceptions if there's NO results. In that scenario, use the OrDefault variants.

Comment: I tried, but got an error:"The result of a query cannot be enumerated more than once." so what should i do now?

Answer (score 1):

You can do :

```
var aRole = _allRoles.ToList().FirstOrDefault(rol => rol.RoleId.ToString() == ddlRoles.SelectedValue);
```

Comment: got an error :     The result of a query cannot be enumerated more than once.

Comment: u r kidding me, FirstOrDefault() is very good, but an new error occurred. any idea?

Comment: Modified my answer, call `ToList()` before calling FirstOrDefault

Answer (score 1):

```
var aRole = _allRoles.Single(x=>x.RoleId.ToString() == ddlRoles.SelectedValue);
```

Correct me if I'm wrong but this one is also a possible option

Comment: Sorry I was typing this answer before Arnaud F' answered this question. Its almost the same.

Comment: I got an error,  The result of a query cannot be enumerated more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do:

```
private void BindGvUsersInRole () 
    { 
        var aUsers = 
            (from aspnet_Roles rol in _allRoles
from u in rol.aspnet_Users
            where rol.RoleId.ToString() == ddlRoles.SelectedValue 
            select u).ToList(); 

        this.gvUsersInRole.DataSource = aUsers; 
        this.gvUsersInRole.DataBind(); 
    }
```

Comment: Care to share definition of Role, User and how they are linked? Generally I don't use navigation properties in LINQ queries, but preffer join DBSets

Comment: @ Vitaliy Kalinin shared part of the code, the whole file is too big,I generated it by "ado.net entity model"

Comment: How User is related with Role? Is it n-1 or n-m relation? Do you need plain Users in DataSource or you have bindings for navigation properties also?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void BindGvUsersInRole ()
{
    var roleID = new Guid(ddlRoles.SelectedValue);

    var users = (from rol in _allRoles
                 where rol.RoleId == roleID
                 select rol.aspnet_Users).ToList();

    this.gvUsersInRole.DataSource = users;
    this.gvUsersInRole.DataBind();
}
```